# Create table with distinct counts per quarter by code

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to create a table that shows the following:

```
Code  Q1 Q2 Q3 Total Cost
```

and under the quarter sections, distinct counts of members and total cost.

This is my code (This code could probably be simplified because I think I'm complicating it or being redundant):

```
proc sql;
create table OUTPAT as 
select 
memberNo,
planPayer,
eventDate,
rptGrouper,
cost,
costFacility,
CostProfessional,
ccsCptMajor,
cpt,
cptDescription
from foundry.outpatientEvents
where planPayer="ICX MXXX" and
ClaimatRisk=1 and
eventDate between '01Jan2020' and '30Sep2021' 
and cost>0
and costProfessional>0;  
quit;


/*E&M pull - over 147,000 rows*/

  
/*format date to quarter*/
data EMpull;
set OUTPAT;
real_date=input(eventdate,YYMMDD10.);
format real_date yyq6.;
where (cpt between '99201' and '99215')
      or (cpt between '99241' and '99245')
      or (cpt between '99381' and '99397')
      or (cpt between '99354' and '99355')
      or (cpt between '99401' and '99412')
   ;
run;


proc sql;
create table EMsummary as 
select
cpt,
real_date as year_qtr,
count(distinct memberNo) as member_dist,
count(memberNo) as memberct,
memberNo,
cost,
sum(cost) as totalcost
from EMpull
where (cpt between '99201' and '99215')
      or (cpt between '99241' and '99245')
      or (cpt between '99381' and '99397')
      or (cpt between '99354' and '99355')
      or (cpt between '99401' and '99412')
group by year_qtr;
quit;
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Format your date as a quarter and it should be per quarter

```
proc sql;
create table EMsummary as 
select
cpt,
put(real_date, yyq6.) as year_qtr,
count(distinct memberNo) as member_dist,
count(memberNo) as memberct,
sum(cost) as totalcost
from EMpull
where (cpt between '99201' and '99215')
      or (cpt between '99241' and '99245')
      or (cpt between '99381' and '99397')
      or (cpt between '99354' and '99355')
      or (cpt between '99401' and '99412')
group by cpt, year_qtr;
quit;
```

Comment: The output is not showing as a short table; it's repeating the total dollars in on column and repeating the member_dist counts in another. Is there a way to make it so that total cost and total member_dist shows per cpt per quarter?  Does a proc sort have to be done?

Comment: See the updated query - your GROUP BY needs to match the grouping you want for the table.

Comment: And if that doesn't work, I go back to my previous comment, you need to show a workable example of data (fake is fine) but we don't' know your data so cannot know if your code is correct or not - just a best guess.

Comment: Ok it worked when I removed memberct and that sseemed to get rid of the dupes I was getting.  thank  you